# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] AngularJs in Wordpress

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I'm trying to import AngularJs into a Wordpress website like this:

```
function mytheme_enqueue_scripts() {
  // register AngularJS
  wp_register_script('angular-core', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js', array(), null, false);
  wp_register_script('angular-route', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.js', array(), null, false);

  // enqueue all scripts
  wp_enqueue_script('angular-core');
  wp_enqueue_script('angular-route');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_scripts');
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)
```

I don't know how to solve this. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a value of ng-app attribute in your html then you need to initialize angularjs in your script

```
// if attribute looks like this
<html data-ng-app="youngAppAtrributeValue">

//Need to Initialize angular on script like this
var app = angular.module('youngAppAtrributeValue', []);
//....bla bla bla code here
```